# operation is that trigger performed wants rollback

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g

I want to write a log system about building table. I want that if someone wants to change building table record, the trigger is performed. Triggers task is write to building_log table,which column in building table wants to change. Important: building table is not effected this operation. Is it possible,i am informed when someone wants to change building table but building table is not effected this operation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just asking for a 'trigger': you can read about them [in the excellent Concepts guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/srvrside.htm#CNCPT118).

But Oracle has a built-in feature that does what you want called [Flashback Data Archive](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011)—if you can use that instead I suggest you look into it.

--- edit:

Ok, I think I misread the question. You want to *silently* prevent the update. Leaving aside whether or not this is a good idea, for a `before update` trigger, you can override the `:new` values with the original `:old` values. There is no simple way of doing something similar with an `insert`, but I don't think you are asking for that.

If you really need to silently prevent inserts too, perhaps you could look at exposing a view to your users instead of the table itself, and creating [`instead of`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#i1006376) triggers